# What does being smaller that to a join means in a lattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, lattice-orders, well-orders

This sounds like a very naïve question, but I couldn't find a correct argument to prove/disprove it rigorously.

> Suppose we have a a subset $A$ of a lattice (or any join-semilattice), and some $x\le\bigvee A.$
> Dose this means that there is $a\in A$ with $x\le a$?

The answer is clearly "Yes" in a totally ordered set. But unfortunately, I am working in an arbitrary lattice.
In case you need, the definition of the join $\bigvee A$ says that:

- $a\le \bigvee A$ for all $a\in A$;
- if there is some $b$ such that $a\le b$ for all $a\in A,$ then $\bigvee A\le b.$

Comment: Not directly related, but it may also be of interest to you, the notion of [Distributive semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice#Distributive_semilattices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the statement **isn't** true in arbitrary total orders. For example, consider the obvious ordering on $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and let $A=\mathbb{N}$. Then $\bigvee A=\infty$ but no element of $A$ is $\ge\infty$.

If we restrict attention to *finite* $A$s then the statement in question is trivially true in total orders, and it is also trivially true for arbitrary $A$s in *co-well-founded* total orders, but those modifications are not very interesting.

And in fact the statement is **never** true in non-totally-ordered lattices even for finite $A$s: if $L$ is a non-totally-ordered lattice, let $A=\{a,b\}$ be a pair of $L$-incomparable elements. Then $\bigvee A=a\vee b$ is strictly above all elements of $A$.

---

Things get a bit more interesting if we replace "$x\le\bigvee A$" with "$x<\bigvee A$." Now for example the statement *is* true in all total orders.

It's still not true in all lattices, however, even when $A$ has only two elements: consider the lattice [$M_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#/media/File:M3_1xyz0.svg) and let $A$ be one of the three pairs of incomparable elements. Then $\bigvee A$ is the top element, which lies above the third "intermediate" element of the lattice. A counterexample with $\vert A\vert=2$ also occurs in $N_5$ (exercise), and so we get that the even the modified statement above restricted  to two-element $A$s fails in all *non-distributive* lattices.

---

In short, we have the following results in terms of which versions of the property in the OP hold in which lattices:

- The original property in the OP holds exactly in the **co-well-founded total orders**.
- The variant of that property gotten by restricting attention to finite $A$s holds exactly in the **total orders**.
- The variant of the original property gotten by replacing "$\le$" with "$<$" holds *only* in **distributive lattices**.

This leaves open the question of whether there is a distributive lattice in which the variant of the original property with "$\le$" replaced with "$<$" but allowing arbitrary $A$s fails. <s>I strongly suspect the answer is **yes**, but I don't immediately see a counterexample.</s> EDIT: [I was thinking too hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164395/28111).

All in all, **anything along the lines of the property in the OP seems extremely rare**.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. Does this true for arbitrary lattices? My guess is, it isn't. But couldn't find a counter example.

Comment: @Bumblebee How could it possibly hold for arbitrary lattices when it already fails for total orders (which are lattices)?

Comment: Ohh... my bad! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Bumblebee I've added a bit of detail.

Comment: I realize that, I was actually thinking about $\lt$ rather $\le.$ And my lattice is distributive (somehow I thought it it irrelevant :)). Thank you so much for this detailed answer to my vague question.

Comment: @Bumblebee Ah. I think that asking the distributive case with $<$ as a separate question would be worthwhile (rather than editing this one, since the change in question is significant).

Comment: That is exactly what I am going to do next. I will link it to this question once I posted it.

Comment: Thank you again for this great answer. I posted a new question [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164393/what-does-being-smaller-that-to-a-join-means-in-a-distributive-lattice) Also, would you be able to sketch why distributivity is necessary to hold this?

Comment: @Bumblebee Distributivity is necessary because it's equivalent to no embedding of $N_5$ or $M_3$, and an embedding of either kills your condition as I say above. Meanwhile my claim that distributivity was sufficient if $\vert A\vert=2$ was **false**, I was being silly. See bof's comment to my answer to your follow-up question.