# What does being smaller that to a join means in a distributive lattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, lattice-orders, well-orders

This is a follow up question to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164345/what-does-being-smaller-that-to-a-join-means-in-a-lattice) with more restrictions. It was answered negatively for arbitrary lattices, but mentioned that the result holds "only" in distributive lattices. I would like to know whether being distributive is also sufficient, or not.
So, the question is:

> Consider a subset $A$ of a distributive lattice, and some $x\lt\bigvee A.$ Dose there exist $a\in A$ with $x\le a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My original answer used an infinite example, which per bof's comment above was totally unnecessary.*

In fact my claim mentioned in the OP that distributivity is sufficient if we restrict attention to two-element $A$s was **blatantly false**. Working in the lattice $L$ of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$, take $A=\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ and $x=\{1,3\}$. Now $L$ is about as nice as it is possible for a lattice to be - e.g. it's a Boolean algebra, so a fortiori distributive.

In fact, abstracting from this we have the following:

> Suppose $L$ is a lattice with elements $a,b,c$ such that $a\vee b\not\ge c$ and $a\vee c\not\ge b$. Then setting $A=\{a\vee b, c\}$ and $x=a\vee c$ we have $x<\bigvee A$ but $x\not<$ any element of $A$.

---

What if we modify things further, and simply ask that $x$ be below some *finite join* of elements of $A$?

Here we obviously need an infinite example, and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ provides one: take $A$ to be the set of finite sets and $x$ to be the set of even numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be interested in the notion of [join-prime element in a lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Important_lattice-theoretic_notions).
In any lattice, a join-prime element is also join-irreducible, and the converse holds for distributive lattices.
Also, in any lattice, an element is join-irreducible iff it covers exactly one element.

In case you are allowing the set $A$ to be infinite (for infinite lattices, of course), then the notion is the one of completely join-prime element.
Again, every completely join-prime element is also completely join-irreducible, and the converse holds for lattices which satisfy the *Join Infinite Distributive* law:
\begin{equation}
x \wedge \bigvee_{I\in I}y_i = \bigvee_{I\in I}x \wedge y_i
\tag{JID}
\end{equation}
where $I$ is any set.
Of course every lattice satisfying (JID) is distributive, but the converse doesn't hold.
Again, an element is completely join-irreducible iff it covers exactly one element.

There are dual notions of (completely) meet-prime elements, with dual results connecting them to (completely) meet-irreducible ones, and the dual notion of (MID).